# Is it possible to detect that an android app is either a beta version or production version?

Tags: android, google-play

We use beta staging in google play store. For app side force update functionality we want to detect if our app is either coming from the beta stage or the production stage of the google play store. Is this possible in android apps?

Comment: your question is unclear, but I still answered whatever I could make from it

Comment: Hm I really don't want to start a discussion, but what is unclear about "we want to detect if our app is either coming from the beta stage or the production stage of the google play store" exactly?

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution? @longliveenduro

Comment: @HadasKaminsky unfortunately not

Comment: I also need to determine this.  We use the app version code to tell the user if they have the latest version. But we don't want it telling all our production users their app is out of date just because we launched a new beta.

Comment: Anyone find a solution on this?

Comment: Is there still no solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

It's currently not possible to detect if the app was installed from either the Beta or Production Track on the Play Store.

Assuming your app will be connecting to an API that you own - What you can do is let the API determine if the App is a Beta or Prod App.  For example store the app version number(s) that are considered a Prod app on the API, when the app connects to the API it passes it's version number to the API and the API returns a response with whether it is Prod (The version matches one it has stored) or Beta App (it's does not match one it has stored).

**There are 2 Limitations to this though**:

1. You will need to update the mobile app version number(s) on your API
   when the app is ready to go to production.
2. Mobile apps will be determined by their version number not what
   Track they are on in Play Store.

If you're happy with these 2 limitations then you will only have 1 APK and a means to determine if your app is Prod or Beta.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the Google Play Developer API but it looks pretty painful.

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/edits/overview

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/blob/master/v3/java/src/com/google/play/developerapi/samples/ListApks.java

Answer (score 2):

Like @Jayen said, it is possible using the Google AndroidPublisher Service API. See the following sample code (in Java):

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils;
import com.google.api.services.androidpublisher.AndroidPublisher;
import com.google.api.services.androidpublisher.AndroidPublisherScopes;
import com.google.api.services.androidpublisher.model.AppEdit;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

public class AndroidPublisherService {

    private final AndroidPublisher service;

    /**
     * Constructs a GooglePlayService instance with the specified credentials.
     *
     * @param accountId
     * @param keyStoreInputStream
     * @param keyStorePassword
     * @param keyAlias
     * @param keyPassword
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public AndroidPublisherService(
            String accountId,
            InputStream keyStoreInputStream,
            String keyStorePassword,
            String keyAlias,
            String keyPassword
    ) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        // Specify info for your application 'CompanyName-ApplicationName/ApplicationVersion'
        // This is not part of the authentication, but sample code from Google specifies this.
        final String applicationName = "SomeCompany-SomeApplication/1.0";
        final JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        final HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        final var keyInputStream = Objects.requireNonNull(keyStoreInputStream);
        final var key = Objects.requireNonNull(SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(
                SecurityUtils.getPkcs12KeyStore(),
                keyInputStream,
                keyStorePassword,
                keyAlias,
                keyPassword
        ));
        var credentials = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(accountId)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Set.of(AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER))
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(key)
                .build();
        this.service = new AndroidPublisher.Builder(
                httpTransport, jsonFactory, credentials
        ).setApplicationName(applicationName).build();
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the application with the specified packageName/versionCode is in the production lane or not.
     *
     * @param packageName The package name of the application
     * @param versionCode The version code of the application
     * @return true if the application is a test version (not in production lane), false otherwise.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public boolean isTestVersion(String packageName, long versionCode) throws IOException {
        // Create the API service.
        final AndroidPublisher.Edits edits = service.edits();

        // Create a new edit to make changes.
        AndroidPublisher.Edits.Insert editRequest = edits
                .insert(packageName, null);
        AppEdit appEdit = editRequest.execute();

        // Get a list of apks.
        var tracksListResponse = edits
                .tracks()
                .list(packageName, appEdit.getId()).execute();
        return tracksListResponse.getTracks().stream()
                .filter(it -> !it.getTrack().equalsIgnoreCase("production"))
                .flatMap(it -> it.getReleases().stream())
                .anyMatch(it -> it.getVersionCodes().contains(versionCode));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If your application's version name ([`android:versionName`](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html)) always contains the string "beta" for beta releases, you can retrieve the package name at runtime, and check that.

Use the 
[`getPackageInfo()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)) method to retrieve a [`PackageInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) object which has a versionName String field.

Another approach would be to use the `android:versionCode`. For example, you could decide that your beta releases always have an odd version code, and production releases always have an even one. You could use `getPackageInfo()` to retrieve the version code and make your determination based on that.

Comment: as in the comments of the answers above, you misunderstood our intents, we don't want to have different apks for betas and prod

Comment: That's a terrible reason to downvote an answer (both mine, and harvey_slash's), especially when you don't spell that out in your original request (and still have not done so).

Comment: i think it's pretty clear to anyone who has used the beta distribution channel of google play.

Answer (score -3):

With "beta" or "staging" in your app version name, you can get it with `getPackageInfo()` and check with a Regex or `indexOf`

```
context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, 0).versionName.indexOf("beta") >= 0
```

Answer (score -3):

Assuming the same apk is typically promoted from Beta to Production, the answer by Dizzy suggesting that a call out to some external API is required is the way to go.

However, rather than setting up and hitting your own back-end API, you can just use an android [HttpURLConnnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection) to check the Google Play store details page for your own app id.

If the current user is enrolled in Beta, the app name is presented as "**App Name (Beta)**".

A little further down the page it will also say "**You're a beta tester for this app. Awesome!**"

The page contains a single button labelled either "Install", "Update" or "Installed", from which you can determine whether or not the user has the latest version

On the same page your app can also look up the last production Updated date, and latest production version name.

Sample Java code for how you might implement this below:

```java
boolean isBeta = false;
URL url = new URL("https://play.google.com/sore/apps/details?id=com.example.app");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
  InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
  isBeta = (scanner.findWithinHorizon("\\s\\(Beta\\)", 650000) != null);
} finally {
  urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: First of all this piece of code contains a typo in url "sore"->"store".
Then if you send a simple Get request like shown in this answer, then you will receive the content of the usual page from your production, without any beta text and so on and so for. So this is the wrong answer.