# For an Android library, is there a way to detect whether host Android app is a beta testing build vs production build

Tags: android, android-library, android-build-type

I’m building an android SDK/library.

In the library I want to know whether app is either

- running on simulator
- physical device
- whether it’s in beta testing on google play
- or it’s product build

Based on my knowledge, I can only detect `simulator` vs `physical` based on some checks on `Build` class values. And there is no way for library to know about `beta testing` vs `production` unless the developer of the app using the `library` provides that information via a `public API`

Could someone confirm this limitation OR provide some insights if there is a way to do this ?

> Reason is to route API calls and data to a particular endpoint so various data doesn’t end up skewing production data.
>
> I can do that via different API Keys for all for cases, but that’s off the limits right now.

Comment: Is the simulator/device under your control OR are you using third party beta testers where but don't trust them to skew production data?

Comment: I'm building the library, so there can multiple apps which can be using the library/SDK. I don't have control or knowledge about how the app testing would be done.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible for a third-party library/SDK such as yours to know how, where, or when any developer is running in a testing/QA/production environment. Any real device could be for development or production.

Even for the primary app developer deploying to the Google Play Store there are limited options for track detection as [Is it possible to detect that an android app is either a beta version or production version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24819546/295004) shows.

I agree with you that if there are Development/QA/Production restrictions (i.e. your backend services) you'll need to provide a public API of some kind to your library to select the appropriate one as you've excluded different API keys.

Sadly you'll also have to be prepared that developers will release your library in the wrong state into production causing other business related effects (production data going to QA or the opposite).

Comment: Yeah so it's basically same understanding I've. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.